# Complex regular expression with validation rules and so on

Tags: javascript, regex

Maybe I got killed here but I need to ask if this insane is possible through RegEx, see I have this Javascript/jQyery function for validates VAT number in Venezuela (RIF):

```
function(value) {
        if (value === '') {
            return true;
        }

        var $rif = value.val();
        var $last_number = $rif.substr($rif.length - 1);
        var $number = $rif.substr(0, 8);

        $valid = /^([VEJPG]{1})([0-9]{9}$)/.test($rif_type + $rif);

        if ($valid) {
            if ($rif_type == "V") {
                $sum = 1 * 4;
            } else if ($rif_type == "E") {
                $sum = 2 * 4;
            } else if ($rif_type == "J") {
                $sum = 3 * 4;
            } else if ($rif_type == "P") {
                $sum = 4 * 4;
            } else if ($rif_type == "G") {
                $sum = 5 * 4;
            }

            $n0 = $number.charAt(0) * 3;
            $n1 = $number.charAt(1) * 2;
            $n2 = $number.charAt(2) * 7;
            $n3 = $number.charAt(3) * 6;
            $n4 = $number.charAt(4) * 5;
            $n5 = $number.charAt(5) * 4;
            $n6 = $number.charAt(6) * 3;
            $n7 = $number.charAt(7) * 2;

            $sum += $n0 + $n1 + $n2 + $n3 + $n4 + $n5 + $n6 + $n7;

            $mod = $sum % 11;
            $last_val = 11 - $mod;

            if ($last_val == 11 || $last_val == 10) {
                $last_val = 0;
            }

            if ($last_number == $last_val) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I'm asking if it's possible to write a RegEx to check the same and if so, how?

These are valid VAT numbers:

```
J298081775
J295809000
J298720620
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added some examples to the main post

Comment: what are the rules?conditions?

Comment: If there's a checksum/hash involved (and that's what it looks like), then I suspect the answer is either "no" or "yes but it's enormously complicated and far worse than what you've already got".

Comment: @vks I mean the calculation related to the last digit

Comment: Oh also you should at least declare all those temporary variables with `var`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes the regex will match always but what define if is valid or not is not just the regex, see the rules below (where the arithmetics happen)

Comment: regex is not for arithmatic!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!111111

Comment: @Pointy this code is part of a plugin I wrote for BootstrapValidator library

Comment: @ReynierPM fine, but local variables should be declared. Your code would throw exceptions in "strict" mode.

Comment: @vks so no, it's not possible, right?

Comment: regex is used for extraction ,match,replace etc. of existing data...it cannot add etc....

Comment: Ok, thanks to everyone, the cause of this question is because I'm using `Form Filler` Chrome plugin and for fill up the form it uses in some cases RegEx so I need to write valid VAT numbers but if it's not possible then I still continue filling by hand